# Error when starting the android emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried to run emulator in android studio, emulator is opening but only show a black screen and give some error like **emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'**

**The complete error is as**

> C:\Users\40131230\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_22
>   emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
>   emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:138: curl_easy_perform() failed with code 6 (Error)
>   emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_ga.c:145: Got HTTP response code 0
>   emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.c:92: curl_easy_perform() failed with code 6 (Error)
>   emulator: WARNING: .//android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.c:100: Got HTTP response code 0
>   emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 6 (Error)
>   emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'

**My emulator setting is in screen shot**
[Screen Shot of Emulator setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENYg.jpg)

How to fix this problem anyone help me to fix this error

thank.

Answer (score 1):

Starting the emulator from the command line using this command:

```
emulator.exe -avd <avd_name> -no-audio -http-proxy <proxy_name>:<proxy_port>
```

Comment: In the console, normally is in the down side.